# Mac(Xcode)でのpython3.5の設定について．

Tags: xcode, python, macos

Xcodeでpython3.5の実行をしようとしています．
とりあえずインストールは終え，ターミナル"which python3"と入力すると，"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3"と出力されています．
インストール自体は数ヶ月前に行い，そのときは正しくXcodeでpython3.5を実行することができました．

しかし現在，Xcodeでの設定がうまくいかなくなってしまいました．
(おそらくEl Capitanに更新したためではないかと思われます．)
具体的に言いますと，Xcodeで"Product - Scheme - Edit Scheme"で上記,"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3"のpython3.5を指定する必要があります．
しかし，python3.5がExecutableではなく書類のファイルになっていて，指定することができません．
どうやら".5"という拡張子だと判断されているようです．

どうすればよいでしょうか？
何か解決法があればお願いします．

Comment: その`python3.5`のインストールとは、[`brew`](http://brew.sh/)でのインストールだったのでしょうか？

Comment: いえ，pythonのdownloadサイトからパッケージをダウンロードして行いました．

Answer (score 1):

右クリック→クイックルックで強引な気もしますが一応選択できましたよ

Answer (score 0):

古い質問ですが私の場合Python3.6.8を使う必要がありまして
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`
をコピーして
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python`
にするとクリックして指定できました
動作保証は...