# Xcodeでのpython3の使用について

Tags: python, python3, macos

環境 Sierra10.12.6 Xcode 9.2 python 3.5.1を使用しています．
ターミナル上で`/usr/bin/python`を実行したところ，正常に作動し，バージョンも3.5.1と表示されました．
しかしXcode上でschemaのExecutableを`/usr/bin/python`として実行したところ

> The run destination My Mac is not valid for Running the scheme

というエラーが発生し作動しません．

`which /usr/bin/python`で実行したところ

> /Users/アカウント名/.pyenv/shims/python

が表示されました．

どなたか解決方法がわかる方がいらっしゃいますでしょうか．
宜しくお願い致します．

Comment: python2.7の場合は正常に作動しております．

Comment: 'usr/bin/python'であっていますよね。それであれば、'which usr/bin/python'と実行すると、実行しているpythonのフルパスが表示されるので、それを質問の方に記載してください。

Comment: 追加しました　　また，Executableを/Users/アカウント名/.pyenv/shims/python か/Users/アカウント名/.pyenv/shims/python3にしても同様のエラーが発生しました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/usr/bin/python は、'/Users/アカウント名/.pyenv/shims/python'からのソフトリンクではないかと思われます。Xcodeの場合、ソフトリンクでは動かないようです。

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3240437

xcodeでpython3を動かすことについては、[Mac(Xcode)でのpython3.5の設定について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23357)の質問もあって動作すると思われるので、もう一度設定の見直しをしてみてください。

なお、/usr/bin/pythonは、Appleが設定しているものなので勝手にソフトリンクに変えるのは適切な行為とは言えません。